# In OpenCV how do I make the background black for this image and extract contours of occluded objects

Tags: opencv3.0, hough-transform, canny-operator

I am trying to extract the strawberry image and the container and make the background either black or white. My objectives are

1. Remove the background - make it black
2. Do canny followed by hough to find the rectangle of the box
3. Draw contours for the occluded strawberries and count how many strawberries are there

I am able to proceed partially with some of the tasks, but I am unable to remove the background completely to start with. Here are the images and my attempt so far with the code.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypaqlfmert6emki/src.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrragdxlg5xfcqe/gray.png?dl=0

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
//#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
//#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
//#include <opencv2/video.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  string imageName("");

  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Requires 2 arguments - Usage: program_name <image file>\n");
    return 0;
  }

  imageName = argv[1];
  printf("image name: %s\n", imageName.c_str());

  // variable declarations
  Mat src;
  Mat image;
  Mat imageScaled;
  Mat gray_image;
  Mat gray_edged;
  Mat canny_dst;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
  Point2f computeIntersect(Vec2f line1, Vec2f line2);
  vector<Point2f> lineToPointPair(Vec2f line);
  bool acceptLinePair(Vec2f line1, Vec2f line2, float minTheta);


  float resize_factor = 1.0; //0.2; //0.75; //0.25; //1.0; //

  // load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
  src = imread(imageName.c_str(), IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
  // I am resizing on the original image which is huge. 
  // If you operate on the image
  // pasted here, then you do not need to resize, 
  // since I am pasting the already resized image
  // hence i changed the resize_factor to 1.0 above
  resize(src, imageScaled, Size(), resize_factor, resize_factor, INTER_AREA);

  cout << "resized original image... " << endl;
  namedWindow( "src", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "src", imageScaled);
  waitKey(0);

  // convert to grayscale
  Mat gray, blurred;
  cvtColor( imageScaled, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
  cout << "grayscale image... " << endl;
  namedWindow( "grayscale", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "grayscale", gray);
  waitKey(0);

  /*
  Tried background subtractor (did not work). 
  I think it would work best with a video frame to isolate
  moving object from the static background. 
  This approach may not work for images.
  Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractor> bg = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(150, 8, false);
  bg->apply(gray,fore);
  bg->getBackgroundImage(back);
  .... Not pasting the code around this, since it did not work for me
  */

  //==============================================
  // STUCK here
  // WANT TO ONLY HAVE THE STRAWBERRIES AND THE CONTAINER 
  // AND MAKE THE BACKGROUND BLACK.
  // HOW DO I DO THIS
  //================================================
    GaussianBlur( gray, blurred, Size(7,7), 2.0, 2.0 );

    cout << "gaussian blur... " << endl;
    namedWindow( "gaussian blur", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "gaussian blur", blurred );
    waitKey(0);

    // canny detection
    Mat edges;
    Mat color_dst;
    Canny(blurred, edges, 66.0, 133.0, 3);
    cvtColor( edges, color_dst, CV_GRAY2BGR );
    namedWindow( "canny", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "canny", edges );
    waitKey(0);

    /// Find and draw contours
    findContours( edges, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
    drawContours( gray, contours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);
    cout << "contoured image... " << endl;
    namedWindow( "contour", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 
    imshow( "contour", gray);
    waitKey(0);                       

    vector<Vec2f> lines;
    HoughLines( edges, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, 0, 0 );
    cout << "Detected " << lines.size() << " lines." << endl;
    // draw lines

    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        float rho = lines[i][0];
        float theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line( color_dst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    namedWindow( "lines", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("lines", color_dst);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To get more effective response I recommend splitting this into two questions (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post ) and boil them down to smaller, more bitesized representative examples.